# Where is the reference variable in function loaded in memory between heap and stack?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, heap-memory, new-operator

I've made a function to get "RectTransform" components from all child GameObjects of a parent GameObject.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Test_Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject parent_G;
    RectTransform[] child_R;

    private void Awake()
    {
        child_R = Get_ChildRectTransform(parent_G);
    }

    public RectTransform[] Get_ChildRectTransform(GameObject parent)
    {
        int sum_Child = parent.transform.childCount;
        RectTransform[] temporary_R = new RectTransform[sum_Child];
        for (int i = 0; i < sum_Child; i++)
            temporary_R[i] = parent.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        return temporary_R;
    }
}
```

My question is...
Is "temporary_R" in the Function loaded in Stack?
And Is it terminated after the Function?
Otherwise, is it going to be loaded in Heap as I wrote "new" and as "array"?

Comment: You need to differentiate between the *variable* and the object that the variable's value refers to. In this case, the variable `temporary_R` is on the stack, but the value of that variable is just a reference. The reference refers to an array, which is created on the heap.

Comment: All variables, in a method, are stored on the stack. Value-type variables are their own value. Reference-type variables are a reference to the actual object stored in the heap. So, reference-type variables are a reference stored on the stack that points to an allocation on the heap.

Comment: Then, `child_R` will have `temporary_R`'s reference which is new allocated in heap after the Function, right? If then, does the memories that original `child_R`'s refered to before the function still stay in heap? without no any refering variable, right?

Comment: @ISAACKWON - the benefit of working with a managed language with automatic garbage collection is that *you don't usually have to care about what memory is being used*. Obsessing over minute details like this is not helping you write useful programs.

Comment: Not an explanation about heap and stack I know but just as side note: You could of course also simply use the `GetEnumerator` implementation of `Transform` and Linq and do e.g. `child_R = parent.transform.Cast<RectTransform>().ToArray();` .. probably not much difference in allocation but probably more efficient than multiple `GetChild` and `GetComponent` calls ;)

Comment: I appreciate to all. I have learned a lot from you. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`temporary_R` it a local variable that references to an array of `RectTransform`. The local variable is stored on the stack, and automatically "freed" when the function returns. Even if we typically do not talk about allocating/freeing local variables.

The actual RectTransforms are stored on the heap, either as part of the array-object if it is a value type/struct or or separately if it is a reference type/class. These objects will be released by the garbage collector whenever it gets around to it.

You would typically not worry about allocations like this. `sum_Child` will *probably* be fairly small, so the amount of memory should also be limited. And since it is only kept alive for a short duration it will most likely be collected in gen 0/1, i.e. the cheap kind of garbage collection. I would also assume it is run fairly infrequently, like once per frame.

You would typically only worry about memory allocation when allocating large objects (i.e. >~ 87kb), or allocating very frequently, like inside a tight loop. And even then it is usually a good idea to use a performance or memory profiler to check allocation rates, time spent in GC,  etc to determine if it is a problem.

Comment: Then, the already allocated memories for `child_R` before the function still stay in heap after the function? and it will be collected by GC later? I'm curious about this topic.

Comment: @ISAAC KWON `child_R` if a *field*, so it will have the same lifetime as the object.  There are plenty of resources about the GC, I would start with the [fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)

Comment: I read the details in your fundamentals link. I have learned a lot. I appreciate that. :)